# get Month in portuguese

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the current month and write in portuguese, but NSLocale pt_br is not working...its in english:

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    calendar.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR")
    let components = calendar.components([.Month , .Year], fromDate: date)

    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR")
    let months = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols

    let year =  components.year
    let month = components.month
    let monthSymbol = months[month-1] // month - from your date components
```

Comment: Tudo bem. It works as expected. Consider that the default locale of the simulator is "en_US".

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
let date = NSDate()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"  // use "MMM" for short names

let monthString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date) // "maio"
```

Comment: Hi there, you know why this return first letter lowercase? In english it comes uppercase, but pt_BR remains lower! Thanks for your help

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde most likely that's the default way to name months in that language. if you want to have a capital letter you can always use `.capitalized`